# Modify fancybox html

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to customize the fancybox HTML code?
I want to move out the next and previous buttons outside the .fancybox-outer

Comment: sure, everything is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I have looked around in the documentation but haven't found anything.

Comment: you will not find it in documentation. You will find it in the code. All HTML/JavaScript & CSS is provided. Look at that!

Comment: what about your other question about the transitions? ... o got your answer and deleted the question?

Comment: @RenePot Thought someone had a better idea.

Comment: @JFK The answer was not correct so I went around the problem so the question was no longer relative. If I find a solution I will post hit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. I did not know before that you could extend/replace methods in jquery. But this new method will (with some basic css) slide in from the right and out to the left.

It renders the buttons outside of the fancybox-outer element and it takes the width of the documen. It can probably be optimized a lot.

```
jQuery('ul a').fancybox({
    margin: 0,
    openMethod : 'afterZoomIn',
    nextMethod : 'slideIn',
    nextSpeed : 1000,
    prevMethod : 'slideOut',
    prevSpeed : 1000
});



(function ($, F) {
    var getScalar = function(value, dim) {
        var value_ = parseInt(value, 10);

        if (dim && isPercentage(value)) {
            value_ = F.getViewport()[ dim ] / 100 * value_;
        }

        return Math.ceil(value_);
    },
    getValue = function(value, dim) {
        return getScalar(value, dim) + 'px';
    };

    F.transitions.afterZoomIn = function () {
        var current = F.current;

        if (!current) {
            return;
        }

        F.isOpen = F.isOpened = true;

        F.wrap.addClass('fancybox-opened').css('overflow', 'visible');

        F.reposition();

        // Assign a click event
        if (current.closeClick || current.nextClick) {
            F.inner.css('cursor', 'pointer').bind('click.fb', function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).is('a') && !$(e.target).parent().is('a')) {
                    F[ current.closeClick ? 'close' : 'next' ]();
                }
            });
        }

        // Create a close button
        if (current.closeBtn) {
            $(current.tpl.closeBtn).appendTo('.fancybox-overlay').bind('click.fb', F.close);
        }

        // Create navigation arrows
        if (current.arrows && F.group.length > 1) {
            if (current.loop || current.index > 0) {
                $(current.tpl.prev).appendTo('.fancybox-overlay').bind('click.fb', F.prev);
            }

            if (current.loop || current.index < F.group.length - 1) {
                $(current.tpl.next).appendTo('.fancybox-overlay').bind('click.fb', F.next);
            }
        }

        F.trigger('afterShow');

        // Stop the slideshow if this is the last item
        if (!current.loop && current.index === current.group.length - 1) {
            F.play( false );

        } else if (F.opts.autoPlay && !F.player.isActive) {
            F.opts.autoPlay = false;

            F.play();
        }
    };

    F.transitions.slideIn = function () {
        var current   = F.current,
            effect    = current.nextEffect,
            startPos  = current.pos,
            endPos    = { opacity : 1 },
            direction = F.direction,
            distance  = $(document).width(),
            field;

        startPos.opacity = 0.1;

        field = 'left';
        if (direction === 'right') {
            startPos[ field ] = getValue(getScalar(startPos[ field ]) - distance);
            endPos[ field ]   = '+=' + distance + 'px';

        } else {
            startPos[ field ] = getValue(getScalar(startPos[ field ]) + distance);
            endPos[ field ]   = '-=' + distance + 'px';
        }

        // Workaround for http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12273
        if (effect === 'none') {
            F._afterZoomIn();

        } else {
            F.wrap.css(startPos).animate(endPos, {
                duration : current.nextSpeed,
                easing   : current.nextEasing,
                complete : F._afterZoomIn
            });
        }
    };

    F.transitions.slideOut = function () {
        var previous  = F.previous,
            effect    = previous.prevEffect,
            endPos    = { opacity : 0 },
            direction = F.direction,
            distance  = $(document).width();

        if (effect === 'elastic') {
            endPos[ 'left' ] = ( direction === 'left' ? '-' : '+' ) + '=' + distance + 'px';
        }

        previous.wrap.animate(endPos, {
            duration : effect === 'none' ? 0 : previous.prevSpeed,
            easing   : previous.prevEasing,
            complete : function () {
                // $(this).trigger('onReset').remove();
                previous.wrap.trigger('onReset').remove();
            }
        });
    }

}(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to move out the `next` and `previous` buttons of the `.fancybox-outer` container, you just need to add these CSS rules (in your own custom CSS file and AFTER you loaded the fancybox CSS file)

```
.fancybox-nav {
    width: 60px;       
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: -60px;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
```

​
You said `you have looked around in the documentation but haven't found anything` but the above is well documented in the fancyapps.com website here --> http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful check No. 6, and the demo is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh3B2/)

... but wonder if you will consider this as a correct answer.

Comment: This is the answer, and should have been chosen as so.  Thanks JFK.